# SQL Server connection string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, connections

I have moved a site from a Window Server 2003 server to a Window Server 2008 server (64 bit). The site connects to a SQL Server 2005 database. I imported the database, and I am running it under SQL Server 2014 (64bit).

I have the IIS on the Window Server 2008 server running the site. The site runs in classic ASP. I am attempting to determine what connection object type I need to make the classic ASP website connect to the SQL Server 2014 database.

This is the old DSN:

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=theDatabase;User Id=myID;Password=password
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? If you moved the database to a new server you just put the name of the new server as the `Data Source`. You will also need to make sure you migrated or created the login.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: As Shawn mentioned, the only required change is the `Data Source`.  However, note that the legacy `SQLOLEDB` provider has been deprecated for several years in favor of SQL Server Native client.  If you install the latest version (SQL Server Native Client 11.0) on the web server, you can change the provider specification to `SQLNCLI11.1` along with the server name change.

Comment: @ShawnMelton  I was not sure what provider to put in my connection string.

Comment: Have you tried the same one you use on the previous server?

Comment: @ShawnMelton  I have not used this on another server.

Comment: @DanGuzman  I tried using the sqlncli provider and it did not work.   Here are the strings I used:   `Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=localhost; Database=Calendar;Uid=userName;Pwd=password`  and `Provider=SQLNCLI11; Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS2014; Initial Catalog=Calendar; User Id=userName; Password=password`

Comment: Please provide what you have done/used and the errors you are getting in your question.

Comment: @normandantzig, the `Driver` keyword is not used for an OLEDB connection.  The second form of the connection string should work, if the SQL Server Native Client 2012 is installed on the web server.  As Shawn mentioned, we need the error message to help diagnose the cause.

Comment: @DanGuzman The site has its own error message it gives:  "There was a error connecting to the database" but I don't think that will help.  Where else should I look for a better error message?

Comment: @DanGuzman How would I make sure that SQLNCLI11 is installed as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the application is obfuscating the error message, try connecting with a Powershell script.  Perhaps this will provide more information about the cause of the connection error.  Even if you don't have the Native Client installed, the legacy SQLOLEDB provider that ships with Windows should still work:

```
$connection = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection;

Write-Output "Connecting using provider SQLOLEDB";
$connection.Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Calendar; User Id=userName; Password=password");

Write-Output "Connecting using provider SQLNCLI11.1";
$connection.Open("Provider=SQLNCLI11.1; Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Calendar; User Id=userName; Password=password");
```

To use SQL Server Native Client, check to ensure `SQL Server 2012 Native Client` is listed as an installed program.  It can be downloaded and installed from the Feature Pack downloads: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29065.

Comment: The server did not like the sqlncli11 string but it did like the sqloledb string.  Also, I had a mistake in the password too.